# How do I simplify a Javascript object so I can set obj.BG='red' rather than obj.css("style": "value")

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, attributes, initialization

I have a div object I've created as a drag handle for another div object. I want to add some custom properties and initialise it. I've done this (As you can see I'm using some jQuery):

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
        // initialise object properties & variables
              var SDStartValDragger = {
                beginDragPos: 0,
                currentPos: 0,
                mouseIsDown: false,
                [bg]:css("background-color": "black")
              }
          // make the drag handle change to red while the mouse is over it
                $(".HDragHandle").mouseover(function() {
                  $(this).css({"background-color": "red"});
                });

          // make the drag handle change to black while the mouse leaves it
                $(".HDragHandle").mouseleave(function() {
                  $(this).css("background-color": "black");
                });

//I'm trying to convert to OO coding style, so I can do the previous with 
//              $(".HDragHandle").mouseover(function() {
//                $(this).bg="red"; 
// or similar.
          }
```

I don't understand how I can initialise the `background-color` value of the `css` object(?) for the `SDStartValDragger` object? In the body of my code (post init), I also want to be able to set the `background-color` for `SDStartValDragger` simply by  `SDStartValDragger.bg = "red"`

The html body section looks like this, if it helps?

```
  <body>
    <div id='SDviz'></div>
    <div id='SDscope'>
      <div id='SDvalueSetter'>
        <div id='SDStartValDragger' class='HDragHandle'></div>
        <div id='SDEndValDragger' class='HDragHandle'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='SDvalueContainer'>
      <div id='SDStartVal'>29-02-2013<br/>09:30:01</div>
      <div id='SDEndVal'>13-12-2015<br/>14:30:00</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id='startVal'>0</div>
      <div id='endVal'>0</div>     
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id='currentStartVal'>0</div>
      <div id='currentEndVal'>0</div>     
    </div> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remove the bracket around `[bg]` and unless you actually have `css()` method, you probably wanted that as a string

Comment: Where/how are you using `SDStartValDragger`? There isn't currently any DOM element involved in your code.

Comment: @adeneo please will you be more specific about the scope of the string. Did you mean `bg:'css("background-color": "black")'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `bg` to be an accessor property. It's not at all clear from the question where or how it's supposed to set `background-color`, but here's how you do the accessor part:

```
var SDStartValDragger = {
    // ...your other properties...
    set bg(value) {
      // Use value to set background-color
    },
    get bg() {
      // Return the current background-color
    }
};
```

That requires that the JavaScript engine in the browser support at least ES5 (2009), so for instance doesn't work on IE8, which came out before then.

Here's an example of an object that wraps a DOM element and sets the `background-color` on the DOM element (via jQuery) in response to a `bg` property like the above:

```js
var SDStartValDragger = {
  element: $("#target"),
  set bg(value) {
    this.element.css("background-color", value);
  },
  get bg() {
    return this.element.css("background-color");
  }
};
setTimeout(function() {
  SDStartValDragger.bg = "red";
}, 400);
setTimeout(function() {
  SDStartValDragger.bg = "green";
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="target">This is the target element</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Between you and me I've been on Linux for 20 years, never write commercial code and sometimes go out of my way to NOT work around IE shortcomings ;o)

Comment: @user1108473: :-) But this isn't an IE shortcoming. IE8 was released before ES5 was specified; no surprise it didn't support ES5. Since then, they've released IE9, IE10, IE11, and IE Edge, all with quite good ES5 support (IE10+ have full support, IE9 doesn't quite get strict mode right). Unlike the Bad Old Days of IE6 and IE7, when they basically didn't update the browser for a decade.

Comment: Mea culpa. I do mainframe usability (not as oxymoronic as you might think) and have front-end developers to do the production code. I'm a poor code tinkerer for home projects on my own, known setup, so I don't have to cross the 'T's too much. Thanks for your prompt response :o)

Comment: @user1108473: *"I do mainframe usability (not as oxymoronic as you might think)"* LOL!

Comment: I think I followed your example correctly but the SDStartValDragger object declared in var seems to be updated but not the div with id='SDStartValDragger'. I presumed that somehow the
      var SDStartValDragger = {
        element: $("#SDStartValDragger"), etc, would bind the two. How should these be related? Sorry for the confusion... :o)

Comment: @user1108473: Yes, that will work, provided that the element exists in the DOM as of when the object is created. Or you can do the lookup in the `bg` accessor methods instead if you like, and eliminate the `element` property entirely.

Comment: I isolated why my version of your code wouldn't work for me. Where you'd been specific about the accessor property call with `setTimeout(function() {
  SDStartValDragger.bg = "red";
}, 400);`, I had tried to make it more generic by using `this.bg`, instead of the more specific `SDStartValDragger.bg` but this seemed to return the wrong 'this'! I'd love to find a way round. In the end, to get the effect I wanted, my function now uses an `if` statement on the `id` to differentiate and then act on a specific source object.